# HTML form that redirects

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to make a simple search box that redirects to an URL based on the input of the form, so if I search for "foo" the form would redirect the user to {{STATIC_URL}}/search/foo

I thought I accomplished this with the following code:

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function whatURL() {
        window.location= window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host + "/search/" + document.form1.url.value;
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

and

```
<FORM name=form1>
    <input type=text id="urlval" name="url"onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()" >
    <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" onClick="return whatURL();" value="Search">
</FORM>
```

but it only works when you hit enter, and not when you click on the button using the mouse (Safari 5.1). If I switch the input type from submit to button then the opposite is observed! Is there a better way to remedy this?

Comment: Why are you doing this in javascript? A simple form with method="GET" will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the onSubmit handler for the form instead of the onClick handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed the onClick and that worked wonders :)

Comment: sorry there was a 10 minute delay before I could accept and I went to lunch in the mean time !